# render order issue (React)

Tags: reactjs, paypal, render, setstate

I have a Paypal component that executes logic on successful payment.

The goal is to have the `paypal/axios.post` execute first, followed by `this.setState(...)`.

The following code block executes `setState()` *before* the `Paypal` logic, and no payment ever goes through:

```
render() {
    const onSuccess = payment => {
      axios
        .post(
          "http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/ethhash",
          {userInput: this.props.userInput}
        )
        .then(response => console.log(response.data, payment))
            .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };

this.setState({ redirect: true });

if (this.state.redirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/FinishedPaying" userInput={this.state.userInput} />;
    }}
```

If I nest `setState()` inside of either the `onSuccess` or `axios.post` logic, it breaks my (`express`) server. Strangely, the error that my server gives me is that a certain function is not a function...the named function works under all other conditions.

I appreciate any help ya'll can toss my way, cheers :)

Comment: Don't use `setState` in render. Also requests should not be triggered in render

Comment: hmm, thank you for the feedback. Where should `setState` be rendered? And when you say "requets" are you talking about the `axios.post` logic?

Comment: setState can be called in lifecycle methods or any event handler methods. Yes I mean by "requests" -> axios.post in your case.

Comment: setState if you use in render it will call the render and again setState will call render so it will be in infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use the setState in render function, you have to move it some other life cycle of React or you need to call post request based on some user action.

```
onPayment= async ()=>{
 const res=await axios.post("http://compute.amazonaws.com:3000/ethhash",
          {userInput: this.props.userInput}
        )
   // check here if any error if error don't set the setState.

 this.setState({redirect:true})
}
```

Comment: In my code, the .post activates if Paypal returns a successful payment. Is this not a user action??

If I put setState into componentDidMount() I have the same problem...redirect happens before the Paypal logic can execute. Thank you for the feedback, I will try a few things based on your suggestions.

Comment: @HanleySoilsmith: why don't you try the componentWillReceivedProps life cycle method

Comment: I'm not familiar, will do some research. If I remove all of the axios logic it works well (but I need the axios logic somewhere). I'm also going to look to see if protected routes are a thing, because I could maybe put the axios logic on the "/FinishedPaying" page.

Comment: React docs say componentWillReceivedProps is legacy and should be avoided...

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Also, do you have any ideas of why setState is executing before the render if I have it in componentDidMount? I thought componentDidMount was supposed to be the end of the life cycle.

Comment: @HanleySoilsmith: because you are making an API call which is asynchronous so  it will call your API and execute the next statement so either you should await it or implement the promises and then you have write the setState once you got the response from server .

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much for your help